# Password field in RowEditing

Tags: extjs, extjs5

I am working on RowEditing, where one filed is a Password field. For that i did tried to bind data like -

> ```
> {
>   text: "Password",    
>   dataIndex: 'password',                                            
>   editor:
>   {
>     inputType: 'password',
>     allowBlank: false
>   }
> }
> ```

What it does is - it binds data as text but if you try to enter password by double click on grid row, then it takes data as password.

How to bind the data to a password textfield? why it is binding text in the first place?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the easiest way to achieve this will be to implement renderer for the password column.

```
{
    header: "Password",
    dataIndex: 'pass',
    inputType: 'password',
    readonly: true,
    renderer: function(val) {
        var toReturn = "";
        for (var x = 0; x < val.length; x++) {
            toReturn += "&#x25cf;";
        }

        return toReturn;
    },
    editor: {
        inputType: 'password',
        allowBlank: false
    }
}
```

Reason it is binding text in the first place is because it doesn't know if that is a password or what. For column it is just a simple text. Editor for that column knows that it is password due to `inputType: 'password'` so it hides it accordingly.

I have prepared this [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1ac6) for you to have a better understanding.

Comment: Thank you for the detail explanation. Its works for me.

Comment: What is the reason behind using "&#x25cf" ?

Comment: It is the html hex encoding for the "black filled circle" which you can see when password is hidden. For more understanding: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/25CF/index.htm

You can use whatever character you want to hide the password.